# filtering listcolumns in the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, tidyverse

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- rownames_to_column(mtcars,var = "car")
mtcars$id <- c(1:length(mtcars$car))
mtcars$make <- map_chr(mtcars$car,~strsplit(.x," ")[[1]][1])

mt2 <- mtcars %>% select(1:4,id,make) %>% nest(-make,.key = "l")
mt3 <- mtcars %>% select(5:10,id,make) %>% nest(-make,.key="m")
mt_make <- left_join(mt2,mt3)

mt2 <- mtcars %>% select(1:4,id,make) %>% nest(-id,.key = "l")
mt3 <- mtcars %>% select(5:10,id) %>% nest(-id,.key="m")
mt_id <- left_join(mt2,mt3)
```

How can I filter `mt_make` to only retain cars with **6 cylinders** and more than **150 hp** and unnest into a dataframe without listcols?

How can I filter `mt_id` to only retain **Merc** with less than **200 hp** and unnest into a dataframe without listcols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, these are not good data structures, because it's really annoying to work in parallel when your data should be related horizontally as in a normal data.frame. I'm assuming that's an artifact of your reprex, though, and your actual data has some better reason for being so arranged. If not, fix your structure for your own sanity.

All that said, you *can* make these structures work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mt_make %>% 
  mutate(l = map(l, ~filter(.x, cyl == 6)), 
         m = map(m, ~filter(.x, hp > 150)), 
         n = map2(l, m, inner_join)) %>%    # collect data where l and m have data
  unnest(n)

#> # A tibble: 1 × 12
#>      make          car   mpg   cyl  disp    id    hp  drat    wt  qsec
#>     <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Ferrari Ferrari Dino  19.7     6   145    30   175  3.62  2.77  15.5
#> # ... with 2 more variables: vs <dbl>, am <dbl>

mt_id %>% 
  mutate(l = map(l, ~filter(.x, make == 'Merc')), 
         m = map(m, ~filter(.x, hp < 200))) %>% 
  filter(map_int(l, nrow) == map_int(m, nrow)) %>%    # assumes your data is parallel, which suggests there's no point to nesting
  unnest()

#> # A tibble: 7 × 12
#>      id         car   mpg   cyl  disp  make    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs
#>   <int>       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     8   Merc 240D  24.4     4 146.7  Merc    62  3.69  3.19  20.0     1
#> 2     9    Merc 230  22.8     4 140.8  Merc    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1
#> 3    10    Merc 280  19.2     6 167.6  Merc   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1
#> 4    11   Merc 280C  17.8     6 167.6  Merc   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1
#> 5    12  Merc 450SE  16.4     8 275.8  Merc   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0
#> 6    13  Merc 450SL  17.3     8 275.8  Merc   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0
#> 7    14 Merc 450SLC  15.2     8 275.8  Merc   180  3.07  3.78  18.0     0
#> # ... with 1 more variables: am <dbl>
```

Comment: The map2 and innerjoining was perfect. Thx